# background image is not displayed

Tags: css

this is my html code inside the page

```
<style type="text/css">
                            .container{width:100%;}
                            .left{float:left;}
                            .right{float:right;}
                            .center{margin:0 auto;}
                        </style>
                        <ul class="invite container" >
                            <li class="container">
                                <span class="left">
                                    <img src="images/main-bride.jpg" height="200px" />
                                </span>
                                <span class="frame right">
                                    <img src="images/main-groom.jpg" height="200px" />
                                </span>
                                <!-- <span class="center" background="images/frame.png"> hello</span> -->
                            </li>

                            <!-- <li class="right">
                                <span class="frame"><img src="images/main-groom.jpg" height="200px" /></span>
                            </li> -->

                        </ul>
```

and this is the css code:

```
.frame {
display: block;
line-height: 0px;
background: url(../images/frame.png) no-repeat center center;
}

.frame img {border: 10px solid #fff;}
```

everything else is working is find but only the background image is not visible. any thing that I'm missing? plz help.

Comment: the path has to be wrong

Comment: is that img inside of your .frame span covering it up...

Comment: No sense in searching blind. Open the developer console in your browser and read the error.

Comment: @cport1 no, tried fixing background-size

Comment: Why my answer was downvoted? Sorry for interrupting this discussion, but it is always nice to say why the answer is wrong, and not just click downvote... While it is not wrong.

Comment: @JacekKowalewski not me.

Comment: No problem :). And does it help? If not, please update Your question or write a comment under my answer, and I will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF Your background should be 10px around the image, than the white border of the image and the image is hiding it.

Try to add:

```
.frame {display: block; padding: 10px; background-repeat: repeat;}
.frame img {border: 0px;}
```

And check if the background is visible "around" the image. Remember that frame.png can be small and still hidden under the image. You must be carefull to adjust all the sizes correct.

Few words of explanation: In that case, You are setting padding on the parent element, so there will be 10px space from each side of the image. In that case 10px frame will be seen from the .frame element, and the image will cover the center of it.

---

If You want the background to overwrite the image, use:

```
.frame img {display: none;}
.frame {display: block; height: ...px; width: ...px;}
```

---

**Why downvote?** It would be nice to write something, thx.

Comment: If You downvote, please write why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand you.

Comment: I mean you're providing debugging tricks not an answer which solves OP problem...

Comment: Just post your trick in the comment area. After OP respond to your comment and if find a solution, OP will tell you to post as an answer...

Comment: No problem, You welcome :). You can set one from both: padding on .frame element, and margin on the image element. But If You set margin on the image element, be sure to set overflow: auto; on the frame element. Good luck and thanks.

Comment: hey, not fixed yet. its only showing up on the right image not on the left. whats wrong with it?

Comment: If an image is 200px x 200px; the background should be 220px x 220px. Additionally, only the 10px "border" will be visible. Make sure that sizes of image and background match each other. You can remove the `background-repeat` attribute, and make sure that `background-position: center center;` is set on the frame. I hope it helps.

Comment: WOW!!! Dont read the last post. Just add a frame class to the left span. It is missing in Your code... ;)

Comment: @JacekKowalewski i did't that before posting question ;) however it works when I set padding as 20, border as 10. doesn't work with 20padding 0 border, or 10padding, border each. its driving me nuts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69074/discussion-between-jacek-kowalewski-and-ay89).

Answer (score 0):

is that css for the background in a file one level up from the index page  or inline on the index page ? your css for the background url says

```
background: url(../images/frame.png) no-repeat center center;

background: url(..            go up one level
               /images/     down into images folder
               frame.png    find the file called frame.png
        ) no-repeat center center;
```

check your paths.

Comment: css is in /css & html is in / (root)

Comment: if you just put an img tag with that img src straight on  the page, does it show up?

Comment: sorry take the ../ off the front

Comment: we typed at the same time, if it shows on the page without altering then it's your path that's wrong. or did you take the ../ off when put straight on an img tag